# Get the next/previous ID on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML:

```
<form action="" id="product_create" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li id="tab1" data-display="categories-picker"><a href="#">Seleccionar categoría</a></li>
        <li id="tab2" data-display="product-create-step-2"><a href="#">Datos</a></li>
        <li id="tab3" data-display="product-create-step-3" style="display: none"><a href="#">Variaciones</a></li>
        <li id="tab4" data-display="product-create-step-4"><a href="#">Detalles del Producto</a></li>
        <li id="tab5" data-display="product-create-step-5"><a href="#">Condiciones de Venta</a></li>
    </ul>

    <fieldset id="categories-picker">
        ....
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="product-create-step-2" style="display: none">
        ....
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="product-create-step-3" style="display: none">
        ....
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="product-create-step-4" style="display: none">
        ....
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="product-create-step-5" style="display: none">
        ....
    </fieldset>

    <button type="button" name="finish-wizard" id="finish-wizard" style="display:none">Finish</button>
</form>

<button type="button" name="previous" id="previous-step" disabled="disabled">&#171; Previous</button>
<button type="button" name="next" id="next-step">Next &#187;</button>
```

In order to toggle or hide previous/show next I need to get the ID of the previous/next fieldset element when I click on `$(input[name="next"])` or `$(input[name="previous"])` but I made this code:

```
var first = $('fieldset').eq(0).attr('id');
var step = 1;

$('#next-step').click(function() {
    if (step >= 1) {
        $("#previous-step").removeAttr("disabled");
    }

    var current = $('fieldset').eq(step).next('fieldset');
    var previous = $('fieldset').eq(step).prev('fieldset');
    current.show();
    previous.hide();
    step++;
});

$('#previous-step').click(function() {
    var current = $('fieldset').eq(step).next('fieldset');
    var previous = $('fieldset').eq(step).prev('fieldset');
    current.hide();
    previous.show();
    step--;
});
```

But it's not working fine, can any give me a help?

Comment: the current step is visible. Why not use that fact rather than a step variable to decide which one is visible and which one should be next. What does *"it's not working fine"* mean? What exactly is it doing, and what did you expect it to do?

Comment: @KevinB it's not working because at got two fieldset always visible and only one should be displayed, not sure where my error is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably simpler, duplicate the functionality with `.prev()` instead of `.next()` to get the code for the prev button.

```
$('fieldset.step').hide().eq(0).show();

$('#next-step').click(function() {

    var current = $('fieldset.step:visible'),
        next = current.next('fieldset.step');
    if (next.length === 0) {
        next = current.nextUntil('fieldset.step').next('fieldset.step');
    }
    current.hide();
    next.show();
    if (next.nextUntil('fieldset.step').next('fieldset.step').add(next.next('fieldset.step')).length === 0) {
        $("#next-step").prop("disabled",true);
    }
    $("#previous-step").prop("disabled",false);
});

$('#previous-step').click(function() {

    var current = $('fieldset.step:visible'),
        prev = current.prev('fieldset.step');
    if (prev.length === 0) {
        prev = current.prevUntil('fieldset.step').prev('fieldset.step');
    }
    current.hide();
    prev.show();
    if (prev.prevUntil('fieldset.step').prev('fieldset.step').add(prev.prev('fieldset.step')).length === 0) {
        $("#previous-step").prop("disabled",true);
    }
    $("#next-step").prop("disabled",false);
});
```

don't forget to give the fieldsets that need to be cycled through a `.step` class. The id's are no longer needed.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h29bP/4/)

Comment: I was cooking up something similar, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/DYnVe/

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly since it's almost exactly the same aside from using .prev instead of .next, i left it out.

Comment: Didn't work since when I click next button in the first fieldset it disabled instantaneously and nothing happen

Comment: Updated, needed to specify a selector in next and prev methods. Added fiddle too, based on @tymeJV's fiddle

Comment: Excelent @KevinB just one more thing that I forgot to tell, if you notice there is a `li#tab3` which have `display:none` in that case I should skip the fieldset corresponding to that LI in this case is `fieldset#product-create-step-3` if I remove the `display:none` from that LI then the flow is as it does right now, what else I need to add to your code in order to add this part?

Comment: Remove the .step class from that fieldset and my code should ignore it.

Comment: Ahhhh I notice something else, go to the end and then go to the first, when you're in the first fieldset previous button never is disabled and you can go backward

Comment: I'm not seeing that in the fiddle

Comment: Hmm yes, I'll check my code, I removed the class from `fieldset#product-create-step-3` as you suggested but then the next button is disabled and I can continue even if `fieldset#product-create-step-4` and `fieldset#product-create-step-5` have `step` class

Comment: Oh, derp. .next() only gets the next, not the next that matches selector. fixing...

Comment: I think in somethink like this `if($('#tab3').is('hidden') && $("tab3").attr('data-display') == next.attr('id')) { // move to next one or previous one depending on action }` but not sure if this was work, pretty sure it does not work :-(

Comment: Updated to fix .next and .prev issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var fieldsets = $('#product_create>fieldset');
    var now = 0; // currently shown fieldset
    fieldsets.hide().first().show(); // hide all fieldsets except first
    $("#next-step").click(function() {
        fieldsets.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now + 1 < fieldsets.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
        fieldsets.eq(now).show(); // show next
        if(now + 1 == fieldsets.length)
        {
            $("#next-step").attr("disabled", "disbaled");
        }
        else if(now + 1 >= 1)
        {
            $("#previous-step").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
    $("#previous-step").click(function() {
        fieldsets.eq(now).hide();
        now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : fieldsets.length - 1;
        fieldsets.eq(now).show(); // show previous
        if(now == 0)
        {
            $("#previous-step").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#next-step").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sLUch/1/)

Comment: That works but if I go trough next and then come back trough previous at the end boht button are disabled, I tested on JSFIDDLE

Comment: i realized that and fixed it already. See the my fiddle again :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are tracking the elements with their indexes, you can simply select the next and previous element using simple technique like

```
var previous = $('fieldset').eq(step-1); // To select previous

var next = $('fieldset').eq(step+1); // To select next
```

But I think you are trying to create this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/c48bs/

Comment: In both buttons? Notice I have one for previous and other for netx

Comment: yes, not working since it never show the next and hide the current

Comment: @Reynier, I think you were trying to make this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/c48bs/